# Does VS make a 'virtual solution' for projects without a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Having opened a specific Visual Basic project from source control mapped folders, the project appears to have a solution — containing only it. The properties window says the path is the same folder as the project, but I can’t find the solution file at the specified path OR anywhere in my local drive.

Is it possible the solution file was somehow not checked in or doesn’t exist?

Comment: Yes, VS will auto-generate a solution if necessary.  Where the original programmer stored his .sln file is not guessable, use a telephone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that's just an unsaved solution.

If you hit Save All, VS will show a Save As dialog for that solution file.

Comment: huh, so it does. I can't imagine they wrote the project without a solution or 'saving all' but equally it would be weird the solution wasn't pulled down.